# Image in Assets.xcassets rendering error

Tags: ios, image, rendering, assets

I got some  rendering error When  load image from Assets.xcassets. The picture below is the wrong place：

#### The original image：

[image: Original]

#### Image when rendered:

[image: Error]

Comment: when i take image  out from Assets.xcassets，it work well

Comment: How you are showing that image ? Are you showing that image programmatically (Loading programmatically or adding it in the interface itself) ?

Comment: @Midhun MP  programmatically